# Realtek Firmware Installation Error

Tags: debian, apt, symlink, kernel-modules, realtek

Im working on an odroid HC2, which runs Debian 9 "Stretch".

In my logs, I can see that there is a driver missing for Wifi:

```
usb 1-1: request_firmware(rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin) failed
```

So i installed firmware-realtek package

```
apt install firmware-realtek
```

Follows the output of the installation :

```
root@ohc2:~# apt install firmware-realtek                                       Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firmware-realtek
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 342 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,148 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free armhf firmware-realtek all 20161130-5 [342 kB]
Fetched 342 kB in 0s (582 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package firmware-realtek.
(Reading database ... 60762 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firmware-realtek_20161130-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-realtek (20161130-5) ...
Setting up firmware-realtek (20161130-5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130) ...
ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-4.14.141+.dpkg-bak' => '/boot/initrd.img-4.14.141+': Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.141+
Image Name:   uInitrd
Created:      Sat Sep 14 10:06:40 2019
Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    5722236 Bytes = 5588.12 kB = 5.46 MB
Load Address: 00000000
Entry Point:  00000000
root@ohc2:~#
```

As I can see, the creation of symbolic link failed.

Also, obviously I can't modprobe the module:

```
root@ohc2:~# modprobe rtl8192eu
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8192eu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.141+
```

I´ve already tried to purge and reinstall it.

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: The `firmware-realtek` package only contains the firmware, not the driver and according to the Debian wiki, the [rtl819x](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x) driver is only available for i386 and AMD64. I guess you have to compile this thing yourself, probably from [here](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Freddy's comment, here is the answer :

Install the needed packages to compile

```
apt update
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) git build-essential dkms -y
```

Get the files

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
```

If you are like me on an Odroid HC2, you need to modify the `Makefile` (https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU/issues/34)

```
nano Makefile
```

Change the parameter `CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_P`C to `n` and the parameter `CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI` to `y`

Now compile

```
dkms add .
dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
modprobe 8192eu
```